# Mathjax is incorrectly rendered

Tags: mathjax

I noticed that MathJax is incorrectly rendered.
Here https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/integral-calculator/?f=xsinx&var=&steps=on
under "the integral of the cosine is ..." only integral of cosine on left-hand-side and sine on the right-hand side should be red, not equal sign and `-xcos(x)`.

However, when I click "show math as tex commands", I get `- x \cos{\left(x \right)} + \color{red}{\int{\cos{\left(x \right)} d x}} = - x \cos{\left(x \right)} + \color{red}{\sin{\left(x \right)}}` and this is the string without any errors.

What is causing incorrect color rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you link to uses the `color` extension for MathJax, which redefines the `\color` macro to be compatible with the LaTeX version. In LaTeX, `\color` is a switch that changes the color from there on, rather than MathJax's version where `\color` takes an argument that is what to be colored. So something like `\color{red}{x} + y` usually would produce a red "x" and a black "+ y", but with the `color` extension would produce red "x + y".  This is why you are seeing completely red expressions in the website you linked to.